# Is a C++ program really slower than a similar C program?

Tags: c++, c, comparison, performance

Assume that i have written a program in C++ without using RTTI and run-time polymorphism (no virtual function, no virtual inheritance) and classes don't have private/protected members, also the C++ specific header files are not used (i.e. C header files are used: `cstring`, `cstdio`, ... instead of `string`, `iostream`, ...).

Then i want to write a similar program in C which the first argument type of the functions are corresponded to the related `struct`.

For example:

```
//C++ code

struct Custom
{
    int a;
    Custom() { }
    void change() { }
    ~Custom() { }
};

int main()
{
    Custom m; //init m
    m.change();
    //destroy m
}

/*C code*/

struct Custom
{
    int a;
};
void custom_init(Custom* like_this) { }
void custom_change(Custom* like_this) { }
void custom_destroy(Custom* like_this) { }

int main()
{
    Custom m;
    custom_init(&m);
    custom_change(&m);
    custom_destroy(&m);
}
```

Is the C++ program slower than the similar C program (Generally)? if yes, why C programs are faster then? I know, C++ uses the RAII design pattern for memory management, is it the reason for the slow?

I heard that some people said the C programs is faster... why?

Edit: Why this question is closed? i wanted to know if c++ does something additionally which we don't need, and how it affects the performance (makes it slower? faster? or nothing?).

Comment: Answer would depend on compiler/platform/hardware. Just compile both programs, benchmark. Also, in some cases, chances of accidentally causing screwup may not be worth extra speed.

Comment: Don't close. Don't get offended everytime something is compared to C. I'd for one like to know if there's any situations where this is the case.

Comment: Amusing that you've heard C is faster than C++, because they're both a damn sight faster than everything else that between them they're peas and beans.

Comment: "Assume that i have written a program in C++ without using RTTI and run-time polymorphism (no virtual function, no virtual inheritance) and classes don't have private/protected members, also the C++ specific header files are not used"

If you don't want to use C++ features, just use C.
Also, I don't see how private/protected can influence performance, they are a pure compile-time thing.

Comment: the ctors and dtors of c++ are only language level support for init and destroy methods. The compiler will create the same code for a ctor/dtor as it would for your memory (de)allocation and init/destroy method in c. So in your example the c++ code should be as fast as the c code.

Comment: Actually for such a short-lived program the fact that the C++ runtime library is bigger than the C library, the C++ program is likely to be somewhat slower. I must admit I find funny to talk about ineffectiveness and RAII, RAII doesn't affect performance, it affects correctness.

Comment: @josefx: Did you mean that C does something like RAII in C++?!

Comment: @PC2st: Your c code achieves the same goal as RAII would, resource management. If you have to initialize an object or clean up after you used it, you write a ctor/dtor in c++ and init/destroy methods in c and call them. c++ makes resource management implicit by calling the constructor and destructor functions every time an object is created or destroyed. Using c does not remove the need for resource management, so the c code will have to do the same as the c++ code only with explicit calls to init and destroy.

Comment: A skilled worker might be able to work faster by using equipment without any interlocks, guards, or other safety gear (at least until he maims himself) but the protection such gear provides is  generally more than worth the slight hassle it imposes.  Occasionally it will be impractical to do a task with all the normal safety gear; such situations must be handled very carefully when they're necessary, and are often best avoided, but sometimes bypassing the safety gear really is the best approach.  C++ is C with extra safety gear; even if bypassed, it adds some weight, but it's generally useful.

Comment: @josefx: You're right, it was my fault, i forgot to say that i have assumed the ctor function maybe fails, and i forgot to implement exception handling in C code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ doesn't use RAII. You **CAN** use RAII in your c++ program.
As long as you are doing exactly the same thing in C++ and in C,
both program should be exactly as fast.
Writing fast programs in C or C++ is not a matter of programming language but of what kind of feature you use.

Comment: If we don't use pointers, such as `m` variable in the above example, C++ uses RAII to allocate and free its memory (when an error occurred in the constructor, the allocated memory will be freed) (and if an error is occurred after class initialization, the destructor will be called automatically).

Comment: @PC2st Just because it works LIKE RAII does not mean it IS RAII.

Comment: @PC2st When you say if an error occurs, you mean if an exception is thrown right ? It means that you're using an extra feature you wouldn't have used in C. If you want the comparison to be meaningful you must either do not use exception, either implement exception handling in C.

Answer (score 4):

You'll never know until you try. If the C++ uses anything that C does not (such as constructors, destructors and even non-virtual methods), it *may* be slower.

But the difference will probably be so small as to be unnoticeable.

Early implementations of C++ may have been  slower than C but that's the nature of *any* software. It improves with time.

*Measure, don't guess!* Profile your specific code to see which is faster. But even if C code *is* faster, the price of losing all that extra functionality may be too much. Execution speed is only one speed, and rarely the important one. *My* opinion of which speed is the most important is development speed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to know if c++ do something additionally which we don't need, and how it affects the performance (makes it slower? or nothing?). for example, RAII does what that makes C++ slower? (or may not) and other things that may C++ does to make it slower than C (or may not).

Comment: @PC2st, if you want to know that, then test that. It will depend on the implementation. I could quite easily write a C compiler that generates code slower than g++ (that's actually likely since, based on the assembler output, the g++ guys are much more knowledgeable about optimisation than I). Crikey, I could write a C compiler whose code ran slower than GWBASIC :-) Unless you start comparing _specific implementations_ (so that actual data can be gathered rather than people's anecdotes), the question seems meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's almost certainly false. RAII by itself will not make the program slower. Both C and C++ compilers would probably generate almost identical code for these examples.